# Display the number of entries in one table, for a key shared by two tables in SQL while also including entries with no place in the other

Tags: mysql, join

I'm very new to MySQL, so still learning. Basically, what I currently have is two tables:

Table 1, people, has a name, date of birth, and phone number.
Table 2, meetings,  has a name, meeting date, and meeting time.

The entries in "name" in both tables are the same (although the names are mentioned multiple times), although Table 1 has an extra name, Paul, who has no meetings scheduled (so there are no entries of that person in Table 2).

I want to print out a simple, 2 column result showing:

name | number of meetings

david | 3

john  | 4

jerry | 5

paul  | 0

I am able to print out:

david | 3

john  | 4

jerry | 5

using

SELECT name, COUNT(*) as Number_Of_Meetings FROM meetings GROUP BY name;

although this only really uses the name data in meetings so isn't really going to be helpful when trying to print out paul as well because he isn't included.

Using the people table I can also do the much more complicated

SELECT p.name, COUNT(*) as Number_of_Meetings FROM meetings m JOIN people p ON p.name = m.name GROUP BY p.name;

This instead shows the name entries in people but only the ones with an entry in meetings, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to also show

paul  | 0

I've tried so many options but honestly cannot figure it out.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want all records from the `people` table event when there aren't any matching records in `meetings` you'll want to use a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(m.name) as Number_of_Meetings 
FROM people p 
LEFT JOIN meetings m ON p.name = m.name 
GROUP BY p.name;
```